# Decode JSON File Upload in Falcon REST

Tags: rest, python-3.x, python-requests, falconframework

I am trying to decode the image file that gets uploaded in my `POST` request.

My class file that handles the upload:

```
class Images(object):

    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        name = req.stream.read()
        helpers.write_json(resp, falcon.HTTP_200, {
            'name':str(name)
        })
```

Calling the API, and adding name and image file. 
The image name "youtried.jpg" is the same level as the file "curl.py" that I'm running.

```
url = 'http://localhost/service/images'
files = {
    'name': 'Jon Snow',
    'image': (open('youtried.jpg', 'rb').read())
}

r = requests.post(url, headers={'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'},files=files)

print (json.loads(r.text))
```

I have also tried changing

`name = req.stream.read()`

to

`name = req.stream.read().decode('utf-8')`

and

`name = req.stream.read().decode('utf-16')`

Let me know if there's a proper way of doing this.

Answer (score 7):

Falcon itself does not come with support for handling multipart/form-data requests (including file uploads), so you will have to use a third-party add-on such as [falcon-multipart](https://github.com/yohanboniface/falcon-multipart).

Just install it with pip, like:

```
pip install falcon-multipart
```

and use it as a middleware, like:

```
from falcon_multipart.middleware import MultipartMiddleware
app = falcon.API(middleware=[MultipartMiddleware()])
```

and then in your Images class, read the file or filename with:

```
image = req.get_param('image')
# Read image as binary
raw = image.file.read()
# Retrieve filename
filename = image.filename
```

So, in the context of your code, this is the correct and complete version:

```
import falcon
import json

from falcon_multipart.middleware import MultipartMiddleware


class Images(object):

    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        image = req.get_param('image')
        # only if you need the image data
        # raw = image.file.read()
        filename = image.filename
        helpers.write_json(resp, falcon.HTTP_200, {
            'name': filename
        })


app = falcon.API(middleware=[MultipartMiddleware()])
app.add_route('/service/images', Images())
```

Comment: It would be nice as you can share how we can unittest this endpoint with **simulate_post()** - I call it and get `self.simulate_post('/upload_csv', headers={'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}, files=files)` and get error `simulate_request() got an unexpected keyword argument 'files'`

Comment: I found one article to test upload file https://gist.github.com/amirma/fc8179f8bcb27d7e7c556a419490e8dc

Comment: Trapsilo Bumi, Falcon already supports it -> https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/multipart.html